# How to show an alert box after redirect on PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

Well, the title's pretty self-explanatory. I have a form on an index.html.

And this PHP code to POST that form into an external URL and then redirect to the index again:

```
<?php

Echo "<style>body{background:#3e4744}</style>";
Echo "<style>h2{display:none}</style>";

//extract data from the post
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://blablabla.com';
$fields = array(
    'email' => urlencode($_POST['email'])
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "/";
    </script>      
    <?php
}

?>
```

So, the thing is. How can I show an alert box saying something like: "Your post was succesfully sent" right after the page has been redirected?

Comment: You should do it prior to re-direct.

Comment: Write a success indicator to the session, and include code in the page you're redirecting to that checks the session for it and displays it if present.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the index.html isn't processed on the server, you have to use some client side logic to transfer data from one page to the other. You could use session storage, local storage, cookies or just the url.

An easy way would be to just pass an indicator inside the url hash. To achieve this, you could modify your `window.location` like this

```
window.location = "/#success";
```

and inside the index.html just test, if the url hash is equal to `#success`

```
<script>
    if (window.location.hash == '#success') {
        alert('Success message..!');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This actually works. But... it shows the alert before the index page finishes its loading process.

On the other hand, the url shouldn't be "/success" after the loading's complete.